# How to get this result with and only with SQL?

Tags: sql, database

The question is:

Two tables (`t1`, `t2`)

Table `t1`:

```
SELLER | NON_SELLER
    A     B
    A     C
    A     D
    B     A
    B     C
    B     D
    C     A
    C     B
    C     D
    D     A
    D     B
    D     C
```

Table `t2`:

```
SELLER | COUPON | BAL
A        9        100
B        9        200
C        9        300
D        9        400
A        9.5      100
B        9.5       20
A       10         80
```

Using `SELECT` Statement to get this result:

```
SELLER| COUPON | SUM(BAL)
A       9        900
B       9        800
C       9        700
D       9        600
A       9.5       20
B       9.5      100
C       9.5      120
D       9.5      120
A      10          0  # !!!
B      10         80
C      10         80
D      10         80
```

For seller A `SUM(BAL)` means `sum( B.BAL,C.BAL,D.BAL)`, for B, `SUM(BAL)=SUM(A.BAL,C.BAL,D.BAL)`...

Please find a way with good performance and don't use temporary table.

My solution:
Running this query will get the result but without the row **"A 10 0"**:

```
  select t1.seller, t2.coupon, sum(bal)
  from t1, t2
  where t1.non_seller = t2.seller
  group by t1.seller, t2.coupon
  order by t2.coupon
```

Please help ~~~~~~

Comment: left join don't help , please note the data very carefully

Comment: do you have another table with a list of coupons?
how efficient do you need the query to be? you can always try a outer join with a SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Seller = t1.NonSeller THEN t2.Bal ELSE 0 END), but that not ideal

Comment: @Jammy Lee: I reformatted your question. Please have a look at the edited version and read [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information.

Comment: could you provide the full sql of "SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Seller = t1.NonSeller THEN t2.Bal ELSE 0 END),"?

Comment: @Peter Lang  thanks, the new look is much better

Comment: @Jammy Lee - Please accept Andomar's answer as the right one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for data on all sellers and all coupons.  So let's start with a `cross join` that generates a list of coupons and sellers:

```
select  sellers.seller
,       coupons.coupon
from    (
        select  distinct seller
        from    Table2
        ) as sellers
cross join
        (
        select  distinct coupon
        from    Table2
        ) as coupons
```

For each seller-coupon combination, you're looking for the sum they can buy from other sellers.  This can be accomplished by a left join:

```
select  sellers.seller
,       coupons.coupon
,       case when sum(t2.bal) is null then 0 else sum(t2.bal) end
from    (
        select  distinct seller
        from    Table2
        ) as sellers
cross join
        (
        select  distinct coupon
        from    Table2
        ) as coupons
left join
        Table2 t2
on      t2.seller <> sellers.seller
        and t2.coupon = coupons.coupon
group by
        sellers.seller
,       coupons.coupon
```

The only function of the `case` statement is to replace a `null` sum with a `0`.

The output matches the one in your answer.  Note that this solution doesn't use `Table1`: the list of other sellers is produced by the `t2.seller <> sellers.seller` condition in the `left join`.

Comment: I think for the first table of cross join we should use t1 , not t2, since the data of t2 may not include all sellers :  (
        select  distinct seller
        from    Table1
        ) as sellers

Answer (score 0):

I get another way to this:

```
  select t1.seller, t2.coupon, sum(bal)
  from t1, t2
  where t1.non_seller = t2.seller
  group by t1.seller, t2.coupon 
  union 
  (select seller,coupon,0 from t2 group by coupon having count(seller) == 1);
```

And I don't know if it is better or worst than compare with  @Andomar  :

```
select  sellers.seller
,       coupons.coupon
,       case when sum(t2.bal) is null then 0 else sum(t2.bal) end
from    (
        select  distinct seller
        from    Table2
        ) as sellers
cross join
        (
        select  distinct coupon
        from    Table2
        ) as coupons
left join
        Table2 t2
on      t2.seller <> sellers.seller
        and t2.coupon = coupons.coupon
group by
        sellers.seller
,       coupons.coupon
```